# How to select item of treelist in sitecore programmatically

Tags: sitecore, treelist

I have a office location treelist in a content item, programmatically I have to select a location. How to do it... any information

Comment: You may need to provide some more details about what you have already tried and what is not working. Most likely, you need to select an Item with code and store the ID, but not sure how you are trying to do this right now.

Comment: @JayS I have a content with Office location (treelist field), through program I have to select the office location according to the Geo location of the content belongs. I have a XML of content ID and Geo location, with this reference I have to update more than 3K contents.
if it's a text box, I could assign the value to it. Since it's a tree list I have to select the countries. so How to select the value (as like moving left to right in Content editor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way we set a text value to a sitecore field programatically similarly it is for multilist or treelist any field.
Only difference is in treelist and multilist content ids are pipeline separated e.g.
{GUID for office location 1}|{GUID for office location 2}

So you need to edit the treelist field like below:

```
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{

  Item item = master.GetItem("path of your item");
  if (item !=null)
  {
    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    item["Office Location Treelist fieldname"] = "{40764AF5-F3C9-4B36-8B51-3EF36702E3DB}|{406200EB-E5D5- 
                                47FB-9031-8A49A7C8FC06}";   
                 // Make sure these item ids belong to datasource of your treelist
    item .Editing.EndEdit();
  }
```